# How do I represent a game board using a graph?

Tags: java, graph

I'm provided with this method:

```
public void init(Logger logger, int playerID, int numWalls, Map<Integer, Coordinate> playerHomes){
    //The graph I want to use 
    HashMap<Coordinate, HashSet<Coordinate>> graph = new HashMap<Coordinate, HashSet<Coordinate>>();
```

`init`: Treat this method as if it was your constructor (and therefore, you should not have a constructor, because it will not be called). The engine will call this method once, upon start up. It is here that you must build and store your initial representation of the game, before any moves have been made.

`Logger`, - reference to the logger class

`playerId`, - the id of this player (1 up to 4, for a four-player game)

`numWalls`, - the number of walls this player has

`playerHomes`, - locations of other players (null coordinate means invalid player; 1-based indexing)

The squares on the board are represented as `Coordinate` that have a row and column value.

I'm just confused how I'm supposed to populate a 9x9 game board that is represented as a graph. I'm trying to get each coordinate to have 4 neighbors, unless it is a corner coordinate or a coordinate on the edge of the board.

But I want my keys and values to be represented as

`HashMap<Coordinate, HashSet<Coordinate>`

For example, Location (key) `(0,0)` has neighbors (values) : `[(0,1),(1,1)]`.

Comment: Rather than using a HashSet of coordinates you could encapsulate all the data for each coordinate in another class, possibly called "Tile". That way you can store the players, edges, etc within that Tile class.

Answer (score 0):

Just represent your graph as a two dimensional matrix, where each cell would contain an object specifying its info (e.g. player in that cell). Adjacency is determined by indices into the matrix. If you need to adorn it with more info, e.g. walls and such, perhaps overlay this info using another matrix with the same dimensions.